# curl posting data multiple times for curl_setopt

Tags: php, json, curl

```
$data = array();
$handle = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result=curl_exec($handle);
```

I am too experienced with curl and debugging this code. The data gets posted successfully to the api url, but there is reports of the data being sent to the api 2 to 3 times each. I want to rule out the code above being the problem as I investigate potential a slow loading form after the user clicks submit, some users may click the submit button a couple times due to the form delay.

Do you see anything above that would reveal it being posted the same data two or three times?

Comment: No, that's a pretty solid set of curl code. Have you tried adding a logger right before the curl is initiated? You could then determine if A) it's that the php script is being called multiple times, or B) if it (for some reason) is the curl code? (the former would show one log line for **each** dupe, the latter would show only one log line for the entire set of dupes).

Comment: @r3mus thanks, I disabled that piece of code and echo'd out a word and checked the response when I submitted the form, that help me determine the function was being fired twice as it showed that echo'd word twice. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad it was an easy troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the OP code, it is a solid (and very simple) php curl expression.

The suggestion is to create a simple logger right before the curl is initiated (or in this case an `echo`).

This way, one can easily distinguish between the following:

1. It's the php script is being called multiple times by the client, or
2. It is the curl code looping somehow

If you see one log line for **each** dupe, the cause is **1.** If you see only one log line for the **entire set** of dupes, then the cause is **2.**